# Review numbers don't add up?

Tags: bug

At the top bar of the site on PC, I see this:
[image]

The mouseover says 5 total posts awaiting review, but when I click on it to get to the review queue, I see this:

[image]

Why don't the numbers correspond? Where are the other 4 posts to review?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number displayed at the top is not a number of posts for you specifically, but a "global" number of reviews in the system. For example, if someone votes "Leave Open" on a close vote review, the post is still an active review for others, so the displayed number is not changed.

You can read more about requests to change this on Meta

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238515/29933
- [Review Count - Fix It or Lose It](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238472/review-count-fix-it-or-lose-it)
- [Wrong posts number on Review section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237845/wrong-posts-number-on-review-section)
- https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/phantom-review-count/916#916